# Extract data from webpage table using VBA

Tags: vba

I would like extract the data from table in webpage. 
my html table code looks like below

```
<table class=table_x_write cellspacing=1
bordercolordark=#d5d5d5 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
align=center bgcolor=#FFFFFF bordercolorlight=#a5a5a5
border=1>
<tr>
    <td class="title_1" align="right" width="20%">
        <div align=right>case number：</div></td>
    <td class="item_1" width="30%"><input type="text" name="sgdabh" tabindex="1" value="3710140068" readonly="readonly" style="width:98%" class="bg0" id="sgdabhD"></td>
    <TD class="title_1" align="right">participant number：</td>
    <td class="item_1" width="30%"><span
        onmouseover="setEnabled('cyfbh',1)"
        onmouseout="setEnabled('cyfbh',2)"> <select name="cyfbh" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option>
        <option value="371014006801" selected="selected">371014006801-passenger car</option>
        <option value="371014006802">371014006802-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option></select> </span></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <TD class="title_1" align="right">licence number - city：</td>
    <TD class="item_1"><input type="text" name="cph_cs" value="豫" style="width:98%" class="bg0"></TD>
    <TD class="title_1" align="right">licence number - letter：</td>
    <td class="item_1"><input type="text" name="cph_zm" maxlength="5" tabindex="6" value="C" style="width:98%" class="bg0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <TD class="title_1" align="right">licence number - number：</td>
    <TD class="item_1"><input type="text" name="cph_sz" maxlength="5" value="8****" style="width:98%" class="bg0"></TD>
    <TD class="title_1" align="right">type of vehicle (own definition)：</td>
    <td class="item_1"><span
        onmouseover="setEnabled('cllx1',1)"
        onmouseout="setEnabled('cllx1',2)"> <select name="cllx1" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option>
        <option value="2">2-two/three electric wheeler</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">3-passenger car(≤9 seats)</option>
        <option value="4">4-HGV</option>
        <option value="5">5-bus(＞9 seats)</option>          
        <option value="6">6-military vehicle</option></select> </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried below code

```
Sub data()
   x = 0
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   For Each w In objShell.Windows
       If w.Name = "Internet Explorer" And w.LocationName = "vehicle data"  Then
        Set externalIE = objShell.Windows(x)
        Set externalIEDoc = externalIE.Document
        Set elemCollection = externalIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        MsgBox (elemCollection.Length)
        For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
            For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                Next c
            Next r
        Next t
        MsgBox (w.LocationName)
        externalIEDoc.getelementsbyname("btnDown")(0).Click
    End If
    x = x + 1
Next
End Sub
```

but I am getting the junk data. I need the value as 
case number：3710140068
participant number：371014006801-passenger car
   I need to extract data from text and selected option. Please help

Comment: Is this from an internal source?

Comment: yes.....this is from source of HTML webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need more than what you get from the following (Note: here I am reading your HTML from a cell into HTML document. You would do it your normal way.). It's obviously not massively robust but I don't think you simply loop rows then columns within and do  HTMLCell.innerText

---

① **Early bound:**

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTableInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = [A1].Text '<== You would obtain in normal way. I just read your HTML in from sheet.

    Debug.Print "Case number: " & html.querySelectorAll("table tr td[class=""item_1""] input")(0).Value
    Debug.Print "licence number - city: " & html.querySelectorAll("table tr td[class=""item_1""] input")(1).Value
    Debug.Print "licence number - letter: " & html.querySelectorAll("table tr td[class=""item_1""] input")(2).Value
    Debug.Print "licence number - number: " & html.querySelectorAll("table tr td[class=""item_1""] input")(3).Value
    Debug.Print "participant number: " & html.querySelectorAll("table tr td[class=""item_1""] option[selected=""selected""]")(0).innerText
    Debug.Print "type of vehicle (own definition): " & html.querySelectorAll("table tr td[class=""item_1""] option[selected=""selected""]")(1).innerText

End Sub
```

---

② **Late binding version for OP:**

Without seeing the broader context of the HTML here is a somewhat fragile bit of code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTableInfo()
    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    html.body.innerhtml = [A1].Text              '<== You would obtain in normal way. I just read your HTML in from sheet.

    html.getElementsByTagName ("table")
    Dim b As Object
    Set b = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")

    Debug.Print "Case number = " & b(0).Value
    Debug.Print "licence number - city:  = " & b(1).Value
    Debug.Print "licence number - letter = " & b(2).Value
    Debug.Print "licence number - number = " & b(3).Value

    Dim c As Object
    Set c = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")

    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    For i = 0 To c.Length - 1
        If InStr(c(i).outerHTML, "selected value=") > 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            If n = 1 Then
                Debug.Print "participant number: " & c(i).innerText
            ElseIf n = 2 Then
                Debug.Print "type of vehicle (own definition) " & c(i).innerText
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Output:**

This is the same as with .querySelector.

[image: Output]

Unfortunately, 豫 comes out as ?

---

③ **Parse the HTML:**

You could also parse the HTML. Tailor to your actual full HTML, but here is how you can do it with your snippet provided:

```
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split([A1].Text, "class=""item_1""")
Debug.Print "Case number = " & Split(Split(arr(1), "value=")(1), Chr(32))(0)
Debug.Print "participant number: " & Split(Split(Split(arr(2), "value=")(2), "selected=""selected"">")(1), "<")(0)
Debug.Print "licence number - city:  = " & Split(Split(arr(3), "value=")(1), Chr(32))(0)
Debug.Print "licence number - letter = " & Split(Split(arr(4), "value=")(1), Chr(32))(0)
Debug.Print "licence number - number = " & Split(Split(arr(5), "value=")(1), Chr(32))(0)
Debug.Print "type of vehicle (own definition) " & Split(Split(arr(6), "selected=""selected"">")(1), "<")(0)
```

Comment: HTMLDocument requires adding the references in excel file. as  I don't have the permissions to change the references I need to get  the way directly using the internet explorer object or shell object to extract the data.

Comment: Right. I have done a first version re-write for late binding. Please let me know how it goes. This requires no additional references to be added.

Comment: Did you try the above which I revised for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Yes Modified code helped me a lot. now I could solve my issue, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'junk data'?

For scraping data from table in HTML code I would use sth like this:

```
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim FilePath As String

Dim SHT as Worksheet

Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim RowNum, counter As Long, ColNum As Integer

XMLPage.Open "GET", WEbsite URL, False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
' Debug.Print HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML might use this line to check the 
'content of inner text
Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
Debug.Print HTMLTables.Length
Workbooks.Add
For counter = 0 To HTMLTables.Length - 1
    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(counter)
    Debug.Print counter 'to explore how many tables are in this HTML code
    Set SHT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    SHT.Name = "DataFromTable"
    RowNum = 1
    For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        ColNum = 1
        For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children 'Using this expression
    '<td> is a child of HTMLRow, and then HTMLCell suppose to get you deeper 
    'into the code probably to the data you are looking for
            Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
        Next HTMLCell
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Next HTMLRow
    Set SHT = Nothing
    Set HTMLTable = Nothing
    Set HTMLRow = Nothing
    Set HTMLCell = Nothing
Next counter
```

If you could post original url of the website it would be easier.

Comment: I am sorry I could not post the url as it is password protected login and it is licensed one.

Comment: @QHarr thanks for posting yours solutions. Especially  querySelector, which I wasn't familiar with, seems to be promising to use in the future. I don't have enough reputation points to comment in everywhere.